# How to fix object rotation and make it vertical in Vuforia?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm working on **Vuforia** application in Unity.

How can I make a **3D object**, attached to the ImageTarget to **always be vertical** during the marker recognition?

So that if I will rotate the marker the model won't be upside down, but remain vertical. It should somehow "understand" were is the worlds z-axis, perhaps using sensors of the iPhone.

**Here is an illustration** of what I mean (grey square is a marker, a green guy is a 3D object, attached to it).

Currently if I will rotate the marker the model will also rotate:

[image]

I need to fix the rotation of the model along z-axis so that it always will remain vertical:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Transfrom.LookAt () to make sure the object always camera facing, with Vector.Up as the 2nd argument:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFacing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera m_Camera;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(transform.position + m_Camera.transform.rotation * Vector3.forward,
        m_Camera.transform.rotation * Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

Attach this script to the image target's child (which will be shown on tracking is found). The camera is the AR camera you added in the scene.

Comment: Thak you very much, this is perfect! :)